# Fullscreen Video - not displaying fullscreen

Tags: css, html, video, iframe, html5-video

I am trying to add a fullscreen video to a website but I am having trouble getting it to cover the entire screen.

Originally, I tried using the video tag but this wouldn't work properly on android. Now I am trying iframes and the CSS I am using is:

```
iframe {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background: url(polina.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

No matter what, there is always additional backspace above / below the video.

Is there anyway I can make the video fill the entire screen, happy to loose some off the sides.

Testing url is [here.](http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/OnePointEight/)

Comment: When the aspect ratio of the video (in this case 2.35:1) doesn't match the aspect ratio of the screen you should see black bars. You can stretch the video, but the quality will not be the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found this link and the code it provides does the trick! http://fvsch.com/code/video-background/

```
#video-bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#video-bg > video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* 1. No object-fit support: */

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
   #video-bg > video { height: 300%; top: -100%; }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
   #video-bg > video { width: 300%; left: -100%; }
}

/* 2. If supporting object-fit, overriding (1): */

@supports (object-fit: cover) {
   #video-bg > video {
      top: 0; left: 0;
      width: 100%; height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `width: 1920px;` and `height: 816px;` to your code and it works!

```
iframe {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 816px;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%); 
}
```

Alternatively this could be a starting point for a solution without `iframe`.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
} 

video {
  object-fit: cover;
  width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video width="1920" height="816" preload="auto" autoplay loop>
      <source src="http://dev.charlyanderson.co.uk/OnePointEight/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/BLKLOGO.m4v" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </body>
</html>
```